# Property of undefined while logging in

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When I input a username that exists in my database, everything works fine, the user logs in. But when I type something else, the app crashes with error saying:

> user[0].userName TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of
>   undefined

and points to `var userdb= user[0].userName;`

When I use console.log, it works just fine and it shows the variable..
Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
app.post('/logMeIn', function(req, res) {    
     var inputUsername = req.body.username;    
     userModel.find({userName: inputUsername}, function(err, user) {
         var userdb= user[0].userName;
         if (err) console.log('User does not exist in the database.');
         else if (inputUsername!=userdb) console.log("User does not exist");
         else console.log("You are logged in.");        
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type something like a username that does not exist in the Users collection, mongoose's find cursor returns a null object with the query. Since you want to check if the username supplied exists in the users collection, you only need find a document with that exists with that username either by using the [**`findOne()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) or the **[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find)** methods.

The `findOne()` method seems like the right choice for this because you can query the relevant index if you have put an index on the `userName` field and check to see if a document or None is returned, ideally using a covered index.

However, it is significantly faster to use `find()` together with `limit()` as `findOne()` will always read + return the document if it exists. `find()` just returns a cursor (or not) and only reads the data if you iterate through the cursor.

You will then need to check the result if it's null then conclude the user does not exist based on the null check only:

**findOne() implementation:**

```
app.post('/logMeIn', function(req, res) {    
     var query = userModel.where({ userName: req.body.username });
     query.findOne(function (err, user) {
         if (err) return console.log('User does not exist in the database.');
         if (user) {
             // user may be null if no document matched, check for null
             if (user !== null && typeof(user) !== 'undefined' && user.length > 0) console.log("You are logged in.");
             else console.log("User does not exist.");
         }
     });
});
```

**find() implementation:**

```
app.post('/logMeIn', function(req, res) {    
     var query = userModel.find({userName: req.body.username}).limit(1); 
     query.exec(function(err, user) {
         if (err) return console.log('User does not exist in the database.');
         if (user) {
             // user may be null if no document matched, check for null
             if (user !== null) console.log("You are logged in.");
             else console.log("User does not exist.");
         }       
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. When I try it with findOne() implementation, everything works fine if I enter a user that is saved in the database. But when I enter something else, nothing shows in the console, and the browser is saying: waiting for localhost...?! Do you maybe know why is that happening?

Comment: And when I try find() method it logs me in no matter what I type in.
Thats why I asked in my question what is happening with user[0].userName. Because I think I need to tell what attribute from the document to select.
My json looks like this:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5844d"),
    "name" : "john",
    "lastName" : "smith",
    "userName" : "Jo",
    "email" : "jo@gmail.com",
    "__v" : 0
}

how does user from function(err,user) knows I want user.userName? - @chridam

Comment: Can you put `console.log(user)` just before the if statement in the `exec()` method of the `find()` implementation to check what is being returned from the query?

Comment: When I type in a user which exists in DB it returns all that good stuff.. `[{ id:132394, name: 'abc', userName: 'xyz', ....}]`. And when I type in something else it just return an empty array: [ ]

Comment: So in the latter case it's only a matter of checking the length of the array, I will update my answer to this effect so that you can try again.

Comment: That solved it! Awesome, thank you very much, I understand this a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
userModel.find({userName : inputUsername}).toArray(function (err, users) {
    // Your code here...
});
```

*Addendum:* When you tell Mongo to call your callback function when you make the call to `find`, it doesn't pass in an error and array of objects. Instead, it passes in an error and a **cursor**. Cursors are objects that are used to interact with fetched data. `find`'s return value is also this cursor.

MongoDB cursors have a method called `toArray`, which takes in a callback whose parameters are (hopefully non-existant) error and array of objects.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but I get a TypeError: Object #<Query> has no method 'toArray'. I tried to fix it, but no luck..

Comment: Mind posting the code you tried? My guess is that you've put the `toArray` call inside the function call for `find`. `find` shouldn't return a query, it should return a cursor. You are using MongoDB for Node.js, right?

Comment: I did it exactly as you posted:  userModel.find({userName: inputUsername}).toArray(function(err, user) { ... }. The rest of the code is identical to that in my question. Yeah, I'm using MongoDB and Node.js.